# Catching punctuation in AppleScript for use in a Mail Rule

Tags: sed, applescript

I get a ton of spam mail where the from or reply to has punctuation in the address. Instead of creating a giant rule with a bunch of rows with Contains "!" and such, I want to use a script in a mail rule to send everything from an address with punctuation other than a dot and an at to the trash.

What can I replace = `"hello world"` in the example below to catch punctuation?

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theSelection to selection
    set theMessage to item 1 of theSelection
    subject of theMessage
    if subject of theMessage = "hello world" then
        set mailbox of theMessage to mailbox "Trash"
    end if
end tell
```

I've looked at some get shell script and sed examples but didn't understand how to specify that I only want to find punctuation.

Comment: FYI, `.` and `@` are both punctuation.

Comment: FWIW, applescript does have the means to utilise regex, either with a shell script or with ASObjC. Here is how you can catch punctuation using the former: `set mSubj to "subject with punct!"; set catchAll to do shell script "echo " & mSubj & " | sed -n '/[[:punct:]]/p'"; if catchAll is not "" then display dialog "spam"; ` Replace semi-colons with linefeeds. You could substitute a specific list of punctuation that excluded `.` and `@`, e.g. `[!?%]`. sed's `-n` stops output, the `p` outputs the line *if* it contains punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re looking for is a regular expression; AppleScript doesn’t have them by default. There are a couple of ways around this.

The easiest AppleScript way is to have a whitelist of valid characters, and then check your string to see if it contains anything not in that whitelist.

Because we don’t want to be trashing messages willy-nilly while testing, I’ve replaced the trash line with a display dialog line. Because the AppleScript calls a function, I also do this outside of the `tell` block. While you can call local functions inside a `tell` block, it’s easier in a short script like this to not worry about it.

```
property goodCharacters : "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.@"

tell application "Mail"
    set theSelection to selection
    set theMessage to item 1 of theSelection
    set theSubject to theSubject of theMessage
end tell

if badCharacter(theSubject) is true then
    display dialog theSubject & " is bad."
    --tell application "Mail" to set the mailbox of theMessage to mailbox "Trash"
end if

--return true of the text contains any non-good character
on badCharacter(theText)
    repeat with theCharacter in theText
        if goodCharacters does not contain theCharacter then
            return true
        end if
    end repeat
    return false
end badCharacter
```

The `badCharacter` handler returns `true` if any of the characters in the given string are not in the list of good characters. Otherwise, it returns false.

You may also find these useful when you switch from testing against the subject to testing against what you said you want, which is the from and the reply-to:

```
set theSender to extract address from the sender of theMessage
set theReply to extract address from the reply to of theMessage
```

If you’re familiar with JavaScript, you may find JXA (JavaScript for Automation) more useful, because JavaScript *does* have regular expressions. In the upper left of Script Editor, change “AppleScript” to “JavaScript”.

```
mail = Application('Mail');
trash = mail.mailboxes.byName("Trash")

theSelection = mail.selection();
theMessage = theSelection[0];
theSender = theMessage.sender().replace(/^.*<([^>]+)>/, "$1");
theReply = theMessage.replyTo();
theSubject = theMessage.subject();

//text.search returns the index of the match
//it returns -1 on no match
//so if the result is 0 or greater, it found a match
//the caret (^) reverses the sense of the brackets
//where [a-z.@] would match *on* any character from a to z as well as the period and @
//[^a-z.@] matches any any character *other than* a-z, ., and @
if (theSubject.search(/[^a-z.@]/i) >= 0) {
    mail.move(theMessage, {to: trash})
}
```

Other options might include using a third-party tool to add regular expressions to AppleScript. You might also use `do shell script` to use `sed` or some other command-line tool to parse the text you need parsed; I’m inclined to think running unknown text to the command line is dangerous, however.

And AppleScript does have tools for strings besides `=`. As shown above, it has `contains` (or `does not contain`), but it also has `starts with` and `ends with`. You can even `get the words of` any string, which will remove all punctuation.